# How to upload 3D model data to Google Maps/Earth?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I've been looking into contributing 3D data to Google Maps/Earth. I am not entirely clear how to go about doing this (In [this instructions](https://maps.google.co.in/help/maps/mapcontent/citiesin3d/dataguidelines.html) they have explained how to go about it but in the link with the form to get started they seem to suggest that only organizations can contribute). To start with, I need to clarify the following:

1. I am not part of any organization. I have some 3D models of buildings in my city. Do I have to be connected to some organization in order to contribute?
2. And if the answer to 1 is no, then where do I upload by models?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official post in the official 3D Modeling for Google Earth & Maps forum: [3D program retired](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/3dwh/epXUQA2bJ2s/pw7G8E6wtZ4J)

It is no longer possible for you to submit 3D models for inclusion in Google Earth. To answer your questions: 1. It *was* possible to submit 3D buildings for anyone. 2. This *was* done by uploading them to the warehouse and then filling in a form.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read it is that you as an individual contributor can also submit models via the [3D warehouse](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/). (I assume you have less than 100 models).

The steps seem to be pretty straight forward, if you use SketchUp there is a feature in the program to upload to the [3D warehouse](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/), and if you have a KMZ with the model you can upload to the [3D warehouse](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/) from the site itself (there is an upload button in the top right of that site).