# Is it possible to upload 3D models to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, 3d

I am interested if it is possible to add 3D models of buildings in Google Maps? Although Google (and community) have 3D mapped biggest cities, there a lot of cities that remain *flat* (2D), but have interesting landscape and tall buildings that stand out. For example, my hometown [Rīga, Latvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riga).

As I searched this question, a lot of resources came up that states "nope, the community can no longer add 3D models - Google is now mapping everything with satellites".. but that info is 2-5 years old. And information in different forums is conflicting, so it is worth a shot for a new discussion.

There is even [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376183/how-to-upload-3d-model-data-to-google-maps-earth) with exactly the same question. Since more than 2.5 years have passed I feel that things might have changed, so please do not mark this as a duplicate to a super-old post. :)

Question - is this true? 
Or (even today) it is possible to add 3D models to Google Maps? If yes, then please provide any guide/link/information how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it still is not possible.

> Hello @Diezvai No, It isn't possible right now.
>
> Several years ago when Sketchup was still for Google, we had this
>   ability to create 3D models and submit them for public visibility on
>   Google Earth as dear @ermest mentioned. Also in Map Maker we had some
>   basic tools to create simple 3D models of buildings but both retired
>   years ago. Even we missed the tool for creating flat polygons!
>
> After that (and also simultaneously in labs) Google focused on smart
>   modeling the world. These days system gathers needed information and
>   images from many resources like satellite, aerial photography, photos
>   from users, street view photography and many others to generate 3D
>   models of buildings, trees and even cars! Also system doing same for
>   showing simple models of buildings on Google Maps.
>
> So there is no tool for users to create 3D models and upload them to
>   Google Maps or Google Earth. Maybe currently smart 3D modeling aren't
>   available in somewhere (like Iran for example) but by improving
>   artificial intelligence and more data one day they will.

Source - https://www.localguidesconnect.com/t5/General-Discussion/Is-it-possible-to-upload-3D-models-to-Google-Maps/m-p/1802100/highlight/false#M495932